# Spinning desktop icon on boot (ubuntu-mate)

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments, ubuntu-mate

What are some possible causes of a desktop hanging on boot and you only see a spinning wheel icon as the pointer?

Is there some item in the Grub boot menu I can check?

Should I boot from a USB key and run some type of administrative task?
Running Ubuntu-Mate 16.04